# Depth estimation used in SSL from ego-motion

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, self-supervised-learning

I have read a recent paper called [Kick Back & Relax: Learning to Reconstruct the
World by Watching SlowTV](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content/ICCV2023/papers/Spencer_Kick_Back__Relax_Learning_to_Reconstruct_the_World_by_ICCV_2023_paper.pdf) which tooks inspiration from a famous older one [Unsupervised Learning of Depth and Ego-Motion from Video](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2017/papers/Zhou_Unsupervised_Learning_of_CVPR_2017_paper.pdf), in both of them an equation (equation 1 and 2, respectively) is not entirely clear to me.

For example, in the older paper the formula is the following:
[image]

From what I have understood, if we write $p_s$ using the pinhole camera model, and we assume that the world coordinates are the same also in $p_t$, we can obtain the following formula:
$$p_s = K T_{t->s} T^{-1} K^{-1} p_t $$ where T is the extrinsic matrix for the target frame. Thus, if I understood correctly, why the paper assumes $D_t(p_t) = T$?